# Windows Media Audio 9 player plugin- something for linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, music-player, streaming

I need something to play WMA radio. Do you know any way of doing this on linux?

Answer (score 2):

[Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) should be able to play WMA radio.  It's possible to set up firefox to direct mms:// URIs to mplayer by setting the firefox configuration setting "network.protocol-handler.app.mms" to /usr/bin/mplayer (or whatever the path is for mplayer).

Comment: I need something to play it in totem media player.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a Debian-based distro and a particular player is built without WMA support, you may try a build from debian-multimedia.org.